# The Twig cache isn't working in Slim routes

Tags: twig, slim

It might sound a bit vague, but I'd like to know if anyone has had issues using Twig cache in Slim routes and managed to resolve them somehow.

I passed the parameter to use cache in the global Twig container loading, but it still seems not to use the cache in the routes that render directly in the Action.

```
$twig = new Environment($loader, ['debug' => true, 'cache' => sys_get_temp_dir()]);
```

```
No action está renderizando assim;
/** @var Environment $twig */
        $twig = $this->container->get('twig');
        return $twig
            ->load('exemplo/resultado.twig')
            ->render([
                'dados' => array_map(
                    static fn(Resultado $resultado) => $resultado->jsonSerialize(),
                    $arrResultados
                ),
            ]);`
```

Comment: What do you mean with "*the cache is not working*"? Twig templates are "compiled" to PHP files on the fly. When you enable the twig cache, all this does is store the compiled PHP files in the configured directory in order to boost the performance. So I'm not sure what you are expecting here?

Comment: In slim routes these files are not being saved to be used in cache. In any procedural file, this file html is saved.

Comment: The twig cache doesn't create HTML files. Read my first comment again